# TeXStudio wont compile with TeXLive

Tags: texlive, texstudio

I am new to LaTeX offline compilers and editors (I used Overleaf before, so with LaTeX language itself - I am pretty comfortable). I am unable to compile a simple document using `pdflatex` option.

My OS is `Windows 10`.

TeXLive version is probably `TeX 3.14159265` (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)? I tried typing command `tex --version` into `cmd` and it spat out this answer:

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Copyright 2020 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

TexLive is installed in `C:\texlive` path.

Version of TeXStudio is `3.0.1` and it is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\texstudio` path.

When I write a really simple document and try to `Build & View` option using `F5` key, I get this following error message:

```
Could not start Default Compiler:PdfLaTeX: 
"C:/texlive/2020/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Pokus1".tex
```

I tried few things.

**1)** I tried to go to `Options --> Configure TexStudio --> Check 'Show advanced options' box --> Build --> Commands ($PATH)`
There I changed an empty path into 'C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32' where all the TeXstudio .exe files are located. It did not help.

**2)** I went to `Options --> Configure TeXStudio --> Commands` and I changed all the default command values to point into their corresponding `.exe` files in `TeXLive bin\win32` folder. It also didn't help.

**3)** Lastly, I tried to compile using `cmd`. I placed my `Pokus1.tex` file into a Desktop, I opened my `cmd`, navigated into Desktop path using `cd` command and then I tried to compile it using `pdflatex Pokus1` command. I got this message:

```
C:\Users\s4tyd\Desktop>pdflatex Pokus1
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt

The command name is C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\mktexfmt
Running the command C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe
Use of uninitialized value $ver in scalar chomp at C:/texlive/2020/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLWinGoo.pm line 205.
Use of uninitialized value $ver in substitution (s///) at C:/texlive/2020/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLWinGoo.pm line 206.
Use of uninitialized value $ver in substitution (s///) at C:/texlive/2020/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLWinGoo.pm line 206.
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil:   c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   c:/users/s4tyd/.texlive2020/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under c:/users/s4tyd/.texlive2020/texmf-var/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking pdflatex with pdftex
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl line 600.
fmtutil [WARNING]: inifile pdflatex.ini for pdflatex/pdftex not found.
fmtutil [INFO]: disabled formats: 5
fmtutil [INFO]: not selected formats: 54
fmtutil [INFO]: failed to build: 1 (pdftex/pdflatex)
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 60
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 1
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 1:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl  --user --byfmt pdflatex
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
```

I was pretty surprised here, since at 5th line you can see `kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt`. Does `mktexfmt` stand for `MiKTeX`? Before installing `TexLive + TexStudio` I spent approximately 1 week working with `MiKTeX + TeXMaker`. However when I almost threw my computer from window, after trying for 3 days to get my `glossaries` package working (since MiKTeX doesnt have `perl.exe` and installing `Active Perl` or `Strawberry Perl` did not help) I had it enough with `MiKTeX + TeXMaker` and decided to switch to `TexLive + TexStudio`. I did proper uninstallation and to make sure, after windows uninstall I scanned my computer using file explorer and deleted all the remaining files containing `MiKTeX/TeXMaker` data.

I attach few screenshots showing my default configuration.

If anybody could help my it would be a life saver. I checked all over the internet yet none solution helped.

EDIT:

`Build&View` option using `LaTeX`/`LuaLaTeX`/`XeLaTeX` does not work either. I attach screenshot of the message view that I get (particularly using `LuaLaTeX`, but the error is same for all of them. Also it was done with default option (in `Configure --> Command` no paths were altered and in `Options --> Configure TexStudio --> Check` `Show advanced options` `box --> Build --> Commands ($PATH)` I did not change anything, so it remains empty.

Edit 2: I tried opening `TeXLive Shell` and in `Actions` tab I tried all 3 options. I attach images:

1. `Regenerate filename database`- seems ok to me
2. `Regenerate formats` -this was huge error. See the 2 screenshots below
3. `Regenerate fontmaps` - I am not sure whether this is OK or NOK

Any ideas? I would really like to avoid having to factory reset my whole computer :/

Edit 3: Maybe we are getting closer to the solution! Those are screenshots of System properties --> Environment variables. Look at the PATH there. Any ideas which path should I add there? Perhaps path into bin directory of TexLive?

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately I am forced to delete previous picture since I cannot post more than 8.

Comment: Try running cmd with admin privileges and entering `texhash`. Then try compiling your small document again. What happens?

Comment: Hello, it updates few things in TexLive texhash: "Updating C:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R...
texhash: Updated C:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R.
texhash: Updating C:/texlive/2020/texmf-config/ls-R...
texhash: Updated C:/texlive/2020/texmf-config/ls-R.
texhash: Updating C:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/ls-R...
texhash: Updated C:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/ls-R.
texhash: Updating C:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/ls-R...
texhash: Updated C:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/ls-R.
texhash: Done." However then when I tried to compile using cmd, it threw the same error.

Comment: However in the meantime I tried to reinstall texlive and texstudio and I found some interesting stuff - in my texlive folder, there was a subfolder 2019. When I started using Latex I remember playing with some offline program before switching to Overleaf. And I remember the program was Texstudio. I dont really remember however if I installed TexLive 2019. Definitely not on my own. Maybe Texstudio installed it along with itself? However I deleted the whole folder (in uninstall program there was no option tu uninstall TexLive 2019 of course) and then reinstalled the TexLive 2020.

Comment: Is it just pdflatex that does not work in texstudio or do the other commands not work either?

Comment: I tried to change Build option to LateX, LuaLateX or XeLateX. None worked. Still similar error. I have edited the original post and added picture of the message I get when I try to Build&View using LuaLateX.

Comment: Something is deeply wrong with your TeXLive installation. The best suggestion I have is to back up your work, uninstall/delete everything TeX related and reinstall from scratch.

Comment: Shoot. I have already tried that 2 times before. I uninstalled both of them and then I proceeded to look for and delete all the remaining files using microsoft explorer. I looked around whole C: directory using those keywords: texmaker, texstudio, texlive, tex live, texmf, miktex. Is there anything else I can perhaps try to look for and delete? I also found something saying that if you do have Anaconda for python, then sometimes it might install TexLive core on its own and that it can conflict with your other TexLive installation. I deleted Anaconda, reinstall TexLive and TexStudio but no go.

Comment: Yes this seems to be a problem with TeXlive, not TeXstudio. Perhaps you can open op the TeXLive manager and under "actions" try all those three regenerate options and hope it configures correctly now.

Comment: For what it's worth, `mktexfmt` is not a Miktex command. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/mktexfmt

Comment: Tried to perform those 3 regenerate option. 'Regenerate formats' option was pretty interesting. There was a lot of errors, see new images I added to the original post.

Comment: Have you checked for `system variables path`?

Comment: Check under `System Properties` > `Environment Variables` > `System Variables` > `Path`

Comment: Wow! That might be the source of the problem! There is a huge path and it looks like at least 3 different paths connected together into non existing path. I again attach screenshots in main post. What should I change it to? To the bin directory of texlive?

Comment: I just checked and path looks the same here. It tis used to import commands/programs from several directories to cmd

Comment: Okay. So I really did a factory reset for my computer and after some tex live installation problems I finally managed to start at least compiling. However there is a ton of other problems. Anyways thanks for your help